# binarysearch tree tree.root returns null

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I found binary search tree insertion java code on the website,

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/

and part of the code is like below,

```
    if (root == null) { 
        root = new Node(key); 
        return root; 
    }
```

and I thought we don`t need any return statement because root itself is reference type(Node), so updating root is enough.

so I changed the code like this.

```
class BinarySearchTree {

class Node {
    int key;
    Node left, right;

    public Node(int item) {
        key = item;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

Node root;

BinarySearchTree() {
    root = null;
}

void insert(int key) {
    insertRec(root, key);
}

/* A recursive function to insert a new key in BST */
void insertRec(Node root, int key) {

    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(key);
    }

    if (key < root.key)
        insertRec(root.left, key);
    else if (key > root.key)
        insertRec(root.right, key);
}

// Driver Program to test above functions 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(); 

    tree.insert(50);
    tree.insert(20);

    System.out.println(tree.root);
    }
}
```

but tree.root returns null.

why is this happening?

Comment: `root` is `null` at that point, so there is no reference. This is the time where your first `key` forms the `root`, so it needs to return to `insert()` method and let `insert()` keep its reference. All `root = new Node(key)` does is to *assign* a new reference to the *temporary* *local* variable `root` to this new instance of `Node`. The `root` field is still `null`.

Comment: That `root` is a local variable (method parameter). The `root` field hasn't been changed.

Comment: `root` is initialized with `null` in your constructor, then you call `insert(50)`, which sets `key` from the parameter and `root` as it is initialized, which is `null` in your case.

Comment: You have a local variable `root` hiding field `root`

Comment: thanks for all your replies. I appreciate it. but isn`t that Node type variable root parameter call-by-reference like array?

Comment: The `Node` instance itself is a reference type, but all `root` field/variable itself does is to hold a reference (i.e. the memory address) of the object of `Node` type. When `insertRec(root, key)` is called, a *copy* of the address is passed in to the method as parameter `root`. This local `root` can hold a different memory address and it doesn't affect the `root` field.

Comment: In java reference variables are passed by value in function and methods. Here reference variable is not like c++ and c pointer. If you don't return, it will not effect as expected.

Comment: @amitpandey that's the difference between java and c/c++. We think variables are passed by reference but we forget that they are passed by value in java.

Comment: Thanks for everyone replying this basic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`root = new Node(key);` updates a local variable, it doesn't update the root of the tree (`this.root`), and it shouldn't. Therefore this assignment doesn't update the tree.

When you return the newly created `Node` (as in the original code that you changed did), you can assign it to be either the root of the tree (as the original code did with `root = insertRec(root, key);`) or the left or right child of an existing tree node (as the original code did with `root.left = insertRec(root.left, key);` or `root.right = insertRec(root.right, key);`). That's how the tree is updated.

EDIT: Java is a pass by value language, not pass by reference. When you pass a variable to a method, that method can't change the value of the passed variable. If you pass a variable whose value is `null` to a method, and that method assigns a value to it, the variable will still contain `null` once the method returns.

Comment: thanks for your help, but as Node root is reference type like array. so isn`t that root parameter operates in call-by-reference? still confused

Comment: public static void main(String[] args){
        int[]arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

        change(arr);

        System.out.println(arr[3]);
    }

    public static void change(int[] arr){
        arr[3] = 10;
    }

Comment: arr[3] is changed to 10, isn`t this pass-by-reference?

Comment: @jwkoo No, the reference is passed in to the method, so any manipulation to the object is reflected. But if you do `arr = null;`, then the `arr` *field* won't be affected (i.e. will not become null).

Comment: @jwkoo that's not the same. You don't change the value of `arr`, you change the value of an element of `arr`. If `change` method did `arr = new int[]{1,2,3};`, the original array will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Like others already have pointed out, you need to update your `root` every time you insert an element.

Just `return` the value of root and update your global `root` for the tree.

```
Node insertRec(Node root, int key) {

    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(key);
        return root;
    }

    if (key < root.key)
        root.left = insertRec(root.left, key);
    else
       root.right  = insertRec(root.right, key);

   return root;
}
```

Finally, update your global `root`.

```
tree.root = tree.insert(50);
    tree.root = tree.insert(20);
```

Full code:

```
class BinarySearchTree {

class Node {
    int key;
    Node left, right;

    public Node(int item) {
        key = item;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

Node root;

BinarySearchTree() {
    root = null;
}

 Node insert(int key) {
   return insertRec(root, key);
}

/* A recursive function to insert a new key in BST */
Node insertRec(Node root, int key) {

    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(key);
        return root;
    }

    if (key < root.key)
        root.left = insertRec(root.left, key);
    else
       root.right  = insertRec(root.right, key);

   return root;
}

// Driver Program to test above functions 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(); 

    tree.root = tree.insert(50);
    tree.root = tree.insert(20);

    System.out.println(tree.root.key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* A recursive function to insert a new key in BST */
void insertRec(Node root, int key) {

    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(key);
    }    
}
```

It is called "shadows effect".

That mean your root note from parent class is shadowed by root node in your method.
To fixed it use "this.root" to reference to parent class and initialized the object.

More information : read "Shadowing"  in the article. It explained very well.

http://ocpj8.javastudyguide.com/ch03.html

Answer (score -1):

In your constructor you don't initialise a rootNode. Your key is also not transformed in a Node and you don't set your inserted Node to a left or right node. Also you don't do anything with a node that is equal to the current node you traverse.